# How to check if there are index in liquibase-mongo?

Tags: mongodb, liquibase, mongodb-indexes

Recently on production environment mongoDb version was upgraded to 4.2 so attempto to create index by the same columns but with different name is a root cause of error from mongo db side.

So because of it I need to implement [liqibase mongo](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-mongodb) changeset.

Pseudocode is:

```
if(index by concrete field is exeist){
   rename it to some static_name;
}
```

I can't find how to implement it using liquibase-mongodb tool.
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase supports Precondition. Preconditions checks if a condition is met, and then the changeset executes accordingly. You can more find more information [here](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/advanced/preconditions.html?Highlight=precondition).